# How to plot two stem plots and two box plots in one figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors

```
A=[0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.5]
B=[0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1 1 1]
```

**How to plot their stem plots and box plots at the same time?**

The y-axis should be the probability of the stem plots.

What I am looking for is something like this.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about matlab or matplotlib (a python plotting library)?

Comment: @JoeKington I am so sorry! MATLAB.

Comment: What do you mean for the stem plots? Are they supposed to be histograms, or does the contents of the arrays represent the heights you want for the bars? If the latter, what determines the horizontal value of the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing the box-plots can be accomplished with

```
boxplot([A B], [ones(size(A)) 2*ones(size(B))], ...
    'orientation', 'horizontal', 'positions', [1 1]);
```

After which you can add the stem plots with

```
hold on
stem(xa, ya);
stem(xb, yb);
```

where I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for for `x` and `y`.